# ObjectManager is unusable for me in Magento 2 Unit Tests

Tags: magento2, testing, phpunit

I am following Vinai Kopp's Series on Mage2CodeKata but it gives me an error message when I declare the $objectManager. After seeing these treads:

- [Object Manager in Unit Testing in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104721/object-manager-in-unit-testing-in-magento-2)
- [Magento 2: Fixing Call to Undefined Method Mock_BlockFactory_4b440480::create() Test Failures](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117170/magento-2-fixing-call-to-undefined-method-mock-blockfactory-4b440480create)

I want to try the ObjectManager in Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager not the one in magento/framework/TestFramework/Unit/Helper/ObjectManager

Here is my code:
before class definition:

```
use Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager;
```

after class definition:

```
public function testTheModuleIsConfiguredAndEnabled()
{
    /** @var ObjectManager $objectManager */
    $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $moduleList = $objectManager->create(ModuleList::class);

    $this->assertTrue($moduleList->has($this->moduleName));
}
```

Here is the error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager' not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unit tests you should use `Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager` which allows to create any object with needed arguments (if they aren't passed, mocks will be created instead).

The `Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager` is used only by integration tests and you get the `PHP Fatal error: Class 'Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager' not found` error because the different `autoload.php` file should be used.

For more details, please, see [the testing section](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/test/testing.html) from official the Magento 2 dev docs.

Comment: The test in question is an integration test, not a unit test.

Answer (score 3):

Remember to use the **integration** phpunit.xml.dist as the alternative configuration file for your Run/Debug configuration as following:

[image: PHPStorm configuration for integration tests]

Probably you are using the **unit** phpunit.xml.dist configuration file as default in your settings.

Comment: Also refer to the [Magento 2 - Integration tests Setup - official doc page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/test/integration/integration_test_setup.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was not about to get @joni's fix working with the exact same code that @vinai uses in the video. Since i ran into the exact same problem, i wanted to post what i was able to get working for me.

The call to `Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager` does correctly bring in the right `ObjectManager`, but this class works very differently then how the `Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager` works. The outline of the difference is explained by @Marius here:

[How to obtain the Object Manager in Unit-Tests?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96192/how-to-obtain-the-object-manager-in-unit-tests)

For me i was able to get the tests working with this code:

```
public function testTheModuleIsConfiguredAndEnabled()
{

    $objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);

    $moduleList = $objectManager->getObject(ModuleList::class);

    $this->assertTrue($moduleList->has($this->moduleName));
}
```

The main difference here is that you are calling in the object manager and passing the current class into it with `$this`. You then get a list of all the modules in the same way, but with the method `getObject` instead of `create`. After these changes the test worked for me.

Comment: If the Magento 2 integration test framework has been properly bootstrapped by phpunit, instantiating the ObjectManager is not required. Instead just use `ObjectManager::getInstance()` to get the correctly configured object manager instance. I believe the original poster didn't execute phpunit correctly to use the dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml file, which correctly initializes the autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just use below methods to use objectmanager in your testcase php file,

```
public function testTheModuleIsConfiguredAndEnabled()
{
   /** @var $objectManager \Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager */
    $objectManager = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager();   

    $moduleList = $objectManager->create(ModuleList::class);

    $this->assertTrue($moduleList->has($this->moduleName));
}
```

Remove from top use objectmanager and try with this syntax.

Comment: The outcome now is this error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap' not found

Comment: have you remove var folder, just remove var from root

Comment: Deleted but nothing changed!

Comment: modulelist class is defined by you?

Comment: No I'm following this tutorial: http://vinaikopp.com/2016/02/05/01_the_skeleton_module_kata/

Comment: have you define at top use Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList;

Comment: Yes! of course!